# Annotation boxes not drawing correctly in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.0, printing, annotation

I have about 400 annotation features in ArcMap 10.0 SP2.  The style is a simple text box with an arrow.  The annotation draws correctly when viewed up close on screen but the arrow detaches from the text box when printing or when zoomed out to view the entire 30x42" page.  I switched from labels to annotation to avoid problems like this.

Any ideas on fixing the printing issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The annotation scale settings may be your issue.  The information at [About annotation](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=About_annotation) is relevant to an older version of ArcMap, but the same principles apply.  There's a section on **reference scales** towards the bottom.  I believe this may be the cause of your issue.

Try a read-up on SP2

[Esri Aeronautical Solution 10 Service Pack 2](http://resources.arcgis.com/content/patches-and-service-packs?fa=viewPatch&PID=156&MetaID=1773)

There are a list of issues addressed with SP2 [HERE](http://downloads2.esri.com/support/downloads/other_/EsriAeronauticalSolution-10sp2-Issues_List.htm)